# UINavigationController - Application tried to push a nil view controller on target, what am I missing?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I am having problems to get my Navigation Controller to run properly! If I click in the cell of the table at the RootViewController, it appears not the next ViewController.

Error message reads

> “Application tried to push a nil view controller on target
>   .”

So I alloc something wrong, was my guessing, I probably missing something important from the book I follow.

So the problem appears here in my RootViewController.m:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UINavigationController *navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

    switch ([indexPath row]) {

        case 0:
            [navigationController pushViewController:kundeViewCon animated:YES];
            break;

        case 1:
            [navigationController pushViewController:kalenderViewCon animated:YES];
            break;

        case 2:
            [navigationController pushViewController:wunschViewCon animated:YES];
            break;
    } 
}
```

In my AppDelegate.m I am doing the following things to set a RootViewController as the NavigationController:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

// Navigation Controller

    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

So I got all my other ViewControllers that I want to push, when I click in the Cell. I just can not see my fault or what I am missing!?

Maybe someone can help me and give me a hint! That would be great!

Comment: Where are kundeViewCon, kalenderViewCon and wunschViewCon created?

Comment: this are all separate classes and they are created than in RootViewController.h

Comment: I cant set the (at), coz i am naming a user with it, so the (at)s are existing!class KundeViewController;
class KalenderViewController;
class WunschViewController;


interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    KundeViewController *kundeViewCon;
    KalenderViewController *kalenderViewCon;
    WunschViewController *wunschViewCon;

}

end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RootViewController` already has its navigation controller - you created it in the app delegate. Creating a new navigation controller when you select a cell doesn't make sense. It should probably look more like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch ([indexPath row]) {
        case 0:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:kundeViewCon animated:YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:kalenderViewCon animated:YES];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:wunschViewCon animated:YES];
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, just make sure that when you call `-pushViewController:animated:` the view controller (i.e. `kundleViewCon`, `kalenderViewCon` & `wunschViewCon`) are non-nil. They look like instance variables or properies - just make sure you are alloc/initing them earlier in your code, like in `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thank you very much. I really didnt alloc/init my other ViewControllers before. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new UINavigationController. You need to get you controller from the current window.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController animated:YES];
```

where yourController is one of your instantiated UIViewController (kundeViewCon, kalenderViewCon or wunschViewCon)

Comment: thank you, yeah it works and I needed to alloc/init my other controllers. happy!

Answer (score 1):

For Googlers:

This may also happen if you did not connect your ViewController to the:

> `"<Your Project> App Delegate"`

If you don't do it then your controller des not get initialized.

You also need to rename the class of the ViewController to the corresponding .h / .m file:

> Open the xib file -> select your ViewController -> go to the "Identity Inspector" -> Type in the
>   Textfield "Class" the name of your corresponding .h/.m files.

Connect your ViewController to the App
By right click and drag from the ...AppDelegate to your ViewController
[image]
After releasing click on the corresponding entry:
[image]